# Why does the order of objects in Document Outline in Xcode matter?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been scratching my head over a code bug for nearly a month now, and finally fixed it by changing the order of my objects in Document Outline.

Some background... I'm adding an image editing function in my app. It's an iPad app. After the user has either chosen a photo from Photo Library or taken a picture with the camera, it will segue to a `view controller`. I'm using [HFImageEditor](http://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor) to edit the image, and I've followed the code demo, except that I'm doing it via a Storyboard.
Anyways, I've got it working, but, whenever I pinch-zoom the image, the image will overlap the Toolbar I have at the bottom. I've added code to clipsToBounds and masksToBounds the UIView, but it still overlaps the Toolbar. Initially, the order in the Document Outline had the Toolbar listed first, then the Image Editor Frame View.

- `Image Editor View Controller` (custom `UIViewController`)

  - View (`UIView`)

    - Toolbar (`UIToolbar`
    - Image Editor From View (custom `UIView`)

Then, I switched it around, and the overlapping issue went away. This is what I have now.

- `Image Editor View Controller` (custom `UIViewController`)

  - View (UIView)

    - Image Editor From View (custom `UIView`)
    - Toolbar (`UIToolbar`

So, my question is: why does the order of the object in the Document Outline matter? Is it because it dictates the order in which they are initialised?

Comment: Actually it indicates view hierarchy

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. Read Stanford lecture notes and it says... "Subview order (in subviews array) matters: those later in the array are on top of those earlier". UIToolbar inherits UIView, so if I want the UIToolbar to be on top, it needs to be at the bottom.